# Netflix requests are returning ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE related to IpV6 issue. Why?

Tags: wireless-networking, google-chrome, firefox, router, dns

I am having a problem with Netflix. I posted a detailed question on another stack [exchange site](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/85703/netflix-is-not-loading-properly-in-chrome-on-mac-with-err-empty-response-for-mos) and was advised to ask here. **The main point is that Netflix is not loading in chrome or firefox but loads in safari**. Many of Netflix requests are returning error empty response. The weird part is it works on other devices in the house. It also work on the same device when I connect to another wifi network.

I tried to troubleshoot but could not resolve it, but I narrowed the problem description to simpler form:

The following url `http://cdn0.nflximg.net/images/2378/23162378.jpg` loads in safari but fails to load in chrome and firefox returning `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` .

However, it load fine in ALL browsers when I connect a different wifi network.

What could be the issue? DNS Cache? Router issue? (I tried to restart it but that did not work). It is very odd because this happens on Chrome & FF when connected to a my Wifi network.

Here is an example of curl request when connected to my wifi:

```
curl http://cdn0.nflximg.net/images/2378/23162378.jpg -v -D -H
* About to connect() to cdn0.nflximg.net port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 2600:5801:2:1::188f:c850...
* connected
* Connected to cdn0.nflximg.net (2600:5801:2:1::188f:c850) port 80 (#0)
> GET /images/2378/23162378.jpg HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.24.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0) libcurl/7.24.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8} zlib/1.2.5
> Host: cdn0.nflximg.net
> Accept: */*
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host cdn0.nflximg.net left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
* Closing connection #0
```

Here is when connected to a different network:

```
url http://cdn0.nflximg.net/images/2378/23162378.jpg -v -D -H
* About to connect() to cdn0.nflximg.net port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 107.14.38.65...
* connected
* Connected to cdn0.nflximg.net (107.14.38.65) port 80 (#0)
> GET /images/2378/23162378.jpg HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.24.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0) libcurl/7.24.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8} zlib/1.2.5
> Host: cdn0.nflximg.net
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache
< ETag: "489bf4838c3aba178dd87b6a19b998ba:1444684773"
< Content-MD5: SJv0g4w6uheN2HtqGbmYug==
< Last-Modified: Mon, 12 Oct 2015 21:19:33 GMT
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 17288
< Content-Type: image/jpeg
< Cache-Control: max-age=395311
< Expires: Sun, 25 Oct 2015 18:59:23 GMT
< Date: Wed, 21 Oct 2015 05:10:52 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Timing-Allow-Origin: *
<
```

The only difference in these requests I see is the IP address par.
First curl request: `Trying 2600:5801:2:1::188f:c850...` second curl request: `Trying 107.14.38.65.`

*Update:* the curl commands above lead me to believe that it was an issue with ipv6 configs. So on my mac, I went to network, then chose DHCP configuration, then Selected `Link-local only` for the Configure Ipv6 section and netflix is working on chrome. Yet I am leaving the question open because I still do not understand what's going on.

Comment: You probably have a broken IPv6 configuration. How and why it's impossible to tell with the information given.